# Throwing an exception from SQL Server transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, exception

A .NET application is connected to a SQL Server database. A transaction query is stored in a string in C# code:

```
query = "BEGIN TRANSACTION Trans " +
        "    BEGIN TRY " +
        "    --transaction code goes here (don't worry, it is all parameterised) " +
        "    END TRY " +
        "    BEGIN CATCH " +
        "        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Trans " +
        "        THROW; " +
        "    END CATCH " +
        "END TRANSACTION Trans ";
```

This query is executed as follows:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.connectionString))
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
       conn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // By the way, I know it is bad practice to catch a System.Exception.
}
```

If an exception occurs within the query itself, and I throw it as above, will it be caught be the try-catch block in the C# code?

Comment: Yes. And this sentence is because comments need to consist of 15 characters at least so.

Comment: Read this (http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) for a thorough description of T-SQL error handling. I don't see an explicit `COMMIT TRANSACTION` in your code so you might benefit from reading through the series

Comment: @AlyElhaddad, the exception will be thrown here because you are using `ExecuteNonQuery`. Exceptions may or might not be caught depending ton the T-SQL and app code with other execution methods. See [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/) for more info.

Comment: I assume you mean `COMMIT` and not `END TRANSACTION`, which is not legal T-SQL. Note that `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` does *not* form an actual block (the way `BEGIN TRY .. END CATCH` does), though you can use indentation to suggest it does. If all you intend to do is make the whole thing atomic you'd be better off using an explicit `.BeginTransaction` in your client code, as at least there you won't run afoul of the many ways you can miss errors in T-SQL. (At the very least you want a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` -- read the background info supplied by @MartinCairney.)

Comment: @DanGuzman what if I wanted to `ExecuteQuery` to return some results, and still wanted to throw an exception that C# would catch?

Comment: @MartinCairney so essentially what you are saying is that error handling should be done in the C# code in the client, correct?

Comment: @Al2110, Do you mean `ExecuteReader`? You'll need to make sure all results are consumed to ensure the error is raised on the client. Read the article I referenced for details..

Comment: @Al2110 - read the document I linked to. It discusses proper error handling in T-SQL so that the appropriate error message is returned. You'll also see the difference with the pattern - the `BEGIN TRAN` should be inside the `BEGIN TRY`

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I shall read those docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned if you are throwing it then It will be caught by catch